# How to get the uploaded file name in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

When I Upload a file using binary field in openerp and saved it, at the time of downloading I am not getting the same name as I uploaded from my lacal i.e, my file name is odoo.pdf during upload, while download it automatically changes into model name i.e (pay_slip_doc) pay_slip_doc is my model name, but while downloading I want the same file name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add a field for filename and use it in the filename attribute of the binary field. You can keep this field visible or invisible as per your requirement. The following is the code example for the same:

```
class your_class(osv.osv_model):

    _name = "yourclassname"
    _description = "yourclassdescription"

    _columns = {
        'binary_field':fields.binary('Your binary field'),
        'filename':fields.char('Filename'),
        }
```

And in the form view in your xml:

```
<field name="filename" readonly="1" invisible="1"/>
<field name="binary_field" readonly="1" filename="filename"/>
```

I hope this helps you out.

Thanks And Regards,

Yaseen Shareef

Comment: Glad that I could help...Thanks!